# How to find the users list in oracle 11g db?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

How to find out the users list, which is all created in the `oracle 11g` database. Is there any `command` to find out the users list which we can execute from the Command line interface!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833459/oracle-sql-query-for-listing-all-schemas-in-a-db

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL Query for listing all Schemas in a DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833459/oracle-sql-query-for-listing-all-schemas-in-a-db)

Answer (score 105):

I am not sure what you understand by "execute from the Command line interface", but you're probably looking after the following select statement:

```
select * from dba_users;
```

or

```
select username from dba_users;
```

Answer (score 35):

```
select * from all_users
```

This will work for sure

Answer (score 17):

The command `select username from all_users;` requires less privileges

Comment: Could you add some more description to the solution you provide?

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following: (This may be duplicate of the answers posted but I have added description)

Display all users that can be seen by the current user:

```
SELECT * FROM all_users;
```

Display all users in the Database:

```
SELECT * FROM dba_users;
```

Display the information of the current user:

```
SELECT * FROM user_users;
```

Lastly, this will display all users that can be seen by current users based on creation date:

```
SELECT * FROM all_users
ORDER BY created;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can think of a `mysql database` as a schema/user in `Oracle`. If you have the privileges, you can query the `DBA_USERS` view to see the list of schema.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this query and it works for me.

```
SELECT username FROM dba_users 
ORDER BY username;
```

If you want to get the list of all that users which are created by end-user, then you can try this:

```
SELECT username FROM dba_users where Default_TableSpace not in ('SYSAUX', 'SYSTEM', 'USERS')
ORDER BY username;
```