# How can I query only non-system databases in an Oracle connection?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, system

I want to be able to display a list of all user databases in an Oracle connection, excluding the system databases.

There is a way to differentiate between user tables and system tables within a database. But I could not find any way how I can filter out all system databases.

Does anyone know how it can be achieved ?

Comment: https://blog.dbi-services.com/oracle-system-schemas-vs-created-users/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could come up with the exact answer to my question taking help from another post - [Oracle SQL Query for listing all Schemas in a DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833459/oracle-sql-query-for-listing-all-schemas-in-a-db)

Here is the query that I needed :

```
> SELECT * FROM dba_users u WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dba_objects o
> WHERE o.owner = u.username ) AND default_tablespace not in
> ('SYSTEM','SYSAUX') and ACCOUNT_STATUS = 'OPEN'
```

This will list all the Non-System users/schemas (aka databases) from your database. Make sure you have logged in as SYS user or you grant "GRANT SELECT ON dba_users TO the_non_sys_user"

Comment: Yes that might work as long as you have already created at least one object for the non-system-user.

Comment: Yes, just what I needed :)

Answer (score 2):

When connecting to oracle you will normally connect to ONE database, and within that database you will have a number of schemas. These schemas would be seen as "databases" in some other rdbms systems. Each schema is owned by a DB-User that can be a system- or normal user. All tables/objects created in a schema is "owned" by the owner of the schema.

So a rough method to separate the system tables from user tables will be to consider tables in a schemas owned by a system user as system tables.

If in a database with version 12c and above you can do like this:

```
select t.table_name, t.owner, u.oracle_maintained
from dba_tables t, dba_users u 
where t.owner = u.username
 and rownum < 100;
```

If version below 12c the oracle_maintained column does not exist so you need this work-around. The 35 should be set to the highest used_id for system users. System users are normally the lowest in the database.

```
select t.table_name, t.owner, case when u.user_id > 35 then 'N' else 'Y' end systemgenerated
from dba_tables t, dba_users u 
where t.owner = u.username
 and rownum < 100;
```

Also: the 'and rownum < 100' should be replaced by your own filter on tables.

Comment: thank you! My customer however is specifically interested in adding a filter on the databases / schemas rather than the tables. 

Is there a query (as a join of such tables) that I can run to list only the non-system databases/schemas ? thanks again.

Comment: Also as I understand, the Oracle doc says ORACLE_MAINTAINED column indicates whether the user/schema is System or non-system. If so, can we not filter by this column directly to check for non-system databases ?

References:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_maintained_dba_users.htm
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-309FCCB2-2E8D-4371-9FC5-7F3B10E2A8C0.htm#REFRN23302

Comment: Then it is easy. Normally there will be one schema for one user. So just query "Select username, oracle_maintained form dba_user where <your filter>..."

Comment: Thank you. The precise query that I needed was slightly different however. I have quoted it below as an answer. Nevertheless, thanks for giving the initial direction.